# What does "that's a coped" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> *"Technically every time you go back into the bottle, that's a coped."*

This is from a video of a nail artist. She is applying nail polish and says this.
I think **'the bottle'** is a manicure bottle. I know what **'cope'** means, it's like **'deal with'**. Right?
But I can't understand what is meant by **'that's a coped'**.

Does it mean **'too much'**?

Comment: Can you provide a link to video?

Comment: It is non standard English.  The is no standard noun "a coped".  Are you 100% certain of the transcription?

Comment: https://www.allure.com/video/watch/triple-take-3-nail-artists-transform-their-nails-into-butterflies

Comment: It is 3m 29s. The website has a transcription and says 'that's a coped." It's possible to be a misspelling or something...

Comment: I think she is just saying "that's a coat", which is the only thing that makes sense in context - ie, a coat of nail varnish.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I can understand it if it is a coat. I appreciate it, Daniel.